# Which association to use in this has_many with three resources in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the following resources:

-> Corporation has_many companies 
-> Company belongs_to corporation 
-> Company has_many state (so, the same company can be in many states) 
-> State has_many companies

My problem here is that a Company have the following attributes: name and description.

There is also a phone number for a company, but that phone number varies depending on the state where the company is located.

Here is how I see it from a table point of view:

```
States
id
name

Corporation
id
name

Company
id
name

Company_states
id
company_id
state_id
phone_number
```

How should I set the associations to acomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [has-many-through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class Corporation
  has_many :companies
end

class Company
  belongs_to :corporation
  has_many :company_states
  has_many :states, through: :company_states
end

class CompanyState
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :state
end

class State
  has_many :company_states
  has_many :companies, through: :company_states
end

company = Company.new(name: 'foo', description: 'bar')
state = State.find_by_name('MA')
company.company_states << CompanyState.new(state: state, phone_number: '800-555-1212')
```